# Get a notification with viewWillAppear - in another VC?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Say you have

```
var someVC: UIViewController
```

is it possible to essentially do the following, somehow?

```
get a notification when {
   someVC has a viewWillAppear
   self.#selector(wow)
}

@objc func wow() {
   print("we spied on that view controller, and it just willAppeared"
}
```

Is that possible ?

(Or maybe on didLayoutSubviews ?)

(I realize, obviously, you can do this by adding a line of code **to the UIViewController in question**. That's obvious. I'm asking if we can "add on" to it from elsewhere.)

Comment: What is relationship between those two? like A is presenting B, it is child, it holds reference ...etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want ViewController B to receive a notification when `viewWillAppear` is called in ViewController A? You could do this through the [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) framework. Keep in mind that both VC's have to be loaded for one to receive a notification.

Alternatively, if the two VC's are on the screen at the same time, then I'd recommend a delegate pattern - have VC A tell an overarcing controller class that it's `viewWillAppear` has been called, and this overarcing controller will then inform ViewController B.

To do this using Notifications:
(This is from memory, so please excuse typos)

```
class TestClassA: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // To improve this code, you'd pull out the Notification name and perhaps put it into an extension, instead of hardcoding it here and elsewhere.
        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification.init(name: Notification.Name.init(rawValue: "viewControllerAppeared")))
    }
}

class TestClassB: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(viewControllerAppeared(notification:)), name: Notification.Name.init(rawValue: "viewControllerAppeared"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func viewControllerAppeared(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("other viewcontroller appeared")
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter)

Comment: "You could do this through the Notifications framework. "  Yes, but how?  All I have in B is a variable which points to the VC "A".

Comment: (I commonly use a delegate as you mention, sure. This is a specific question about how to do it in a more agent-based, non-iOS idiom approach.)

Comment: Updated @Fattie

Comment: thanks @jaredh  ..  gotcha - ah, so you do have to do something "in A".  I wonder if there's a way to just get it from inside B, without doing anything in A ???

Comment: @Fattie Not that I'm aware of. If you do find a way, please post the solution bc I'd be interested to see it. :)

Comment: Pls feel free to upvote this answer if it was helpful. Thank you.